Is there a difference between these two layouts?
I am using an SG90 servo motor with a 100nF(C16) decoupling capacitor and a 100µF(C20) bulk capacitor at its power pins. I'm wondering if there's a difference between these two layouts or if both would work equally well?




What else is connected to them? Some length of cable to the header, I assume? What's the rest of the circuit look like? For an introduction, the topic you're looking for is PDN (power distribution network) analysis.

@TimWilliams I posted a screenshot with the entire schematic. There are only coper traces on the PCB that lead to the servo pins. For the PCB layout I just started so I don't really have anything to share.

There are a lot of power rats-nest wires on PCB in the beginning, but if you have through-hole components they usually disappear when you pour copper on power layers. If they won't, it means you route power to other components via servo power traces, which is bad idea as @Spehro'speff'Pefhany pointed out.
Let's assume that those wires lead to other servos and power supply and will disappear. What you left with are two capacitors. Bulk capacitor should have relatively wide traces to servo pins. You won't be able to route those via small pads of decoupling capacitor without breaking clearance requirements. You can use zones instead of traces, of course, but it is cumbersome. So, the second layout is preferable here, from routing perspective.
Alternatively, you can swap the positions of the capacitors on the first layout and have wide traces to the bulk, then continue with thinner traces to decoupling.

Assuming J1 goes to a cable that is relatively long, there's virtually no difference between the two layouts.
That doesn't mean that either one is good enough, just that there is little practical difference. Hobby RC servos draw a lot of current and the path back to the power supply and any larger reservoir capacitors may be important. The whole loop is important. They are also relatively tolerant, but the rest of your circuit may not be.

I am not using cables, the servo motor is directly routed on the PCB, so the power source is fairly close. Does that mean that I don't need the bulk CAP at all?

No it does not necessarily mean that. It's a system level question.

Thank you for clarifying that for me!

There isn't much difference, the traces only contribute less than 1nH and the arrangement only has fempto farads of capacitance difference. So unless you are doing something really fast (like in the GHz range) it isn't going to make a difference.
This could make a difference on CPU or RF designs with capacitor order but it looks like you are not doing that so it doesn't matter.

Hmm, more like 3-5nH, if those are 1206 and 0603, and a 0.1" pitch header, and average width traces are used to connect them.
